# Why Apple create a singleton struct and pass it to the environment?

Tags: swiftui, struct, singleton

When you create an app using Core Data, Xcode creates a struct called PersistenceController that is a singleton.

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext 

    ...
```

then, when the app starts they create the singleton and pass it to `.environment()`

```
@main
struct MyApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        }
    }
}
```

Why did `PersistenceController` is created as a singleton if it is passed to the environment. Isn't the environment holding enough to keep the singleton in memory? And also, isn't the singleton easily accessible by using the shared option without needing to pass it to the environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t have to inject it if you don’t want but there are non-obvious uses for

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
```

Such as

```
@FetchRequest
```

You can omit if you want depending on your code base you’ll get crashes that say it is missing.

Apple uses a singleton because it prevents the store from being loaded multiple times.

Comment: Thanks. I was forgetting about @FetchRequest... Will it load multiple times if it is injected in the environment and then called from that when necessary?

Comment: @Duck not if you have `static let`

Comment: I see. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It's so you can use the preview singleton in the environment for your Previews without having to change the View code.

Comment: ahhh, good catch!